# OpenCV: How do I make a Mat colorized where the Mask is white

Tags: java, opencv, mask, mat

I am new to OpenCV and just doing a basic RGB color filter. I was doing this by testing each pixel, but that's inefficient. So I tried `Core.inRange` but that returns a mask (black and white) and I need a colored `Mat`. Here is what I currently have:

```
// frame is input, out is output
Scalar minValues = new Scalar(RFrom, GFrom, BFrom);
Scalar maxValues = new Scalar(RTo, GTo, BTo);
Mat mask = new Mat();
Core.inRange(frame, minValues, maxValues, mask);
Core.bitwise_and(frame, mask, out);
```

When I run it, I get:

> .CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.2) /Users/jason/Projects/openpnp/opencv/opencv/opencv-3.4.2/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:225: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'binary_op'
>   ]

This is because the `mask` updated by `inRange` has type `CV_8UC1` but the frame has type `CV_8UC3`. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a forum, nor a blog. Please rewrite this into a proper Q and A format, or just delete it. ([ask], [answer])

Comment: Please edit your question, remove the answer part and post it as answer. Srlf answered questions are fine, but they have to be posted in SO question / answer format. You can even accept your own answer, but you should remove "solved" from your title.

Comment: Okay, I rewrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried switching `out` and `frame` in and using `frame.copyTo(out, mask)` instead of `Core.bitwise_and(frame, mask, out)`

It worked!!

Here is my final code:

```
// frame is input, out is output            
Scalar minValues = new Scalar(RFrom, GFrom, BFrom);
Scalar maxValues = new Scalar(RTo, GTo, BTo);
Mat mask = new Mat();
Core.inRange(frame, minValues, maxValues, mask);
frame.copyTo(out, mask);
```

Comment: This actually save my day, the openCV documentation in Java is really bad